# Deploy app to Heroku with custom name using git?

Tags: git, heroku

From [Heroku's guide](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/git), I can only do this:

```
heroku create
```

(there will be a Heroku repository with generated name)

```
git push heroku master
```

then if I want to rename it (I'll have to anyway), I'll do this:

```
git remote rename generated-name the-name-i-want
```

But if I want to create a Heroku repository with a custom name, I can't deploy my code using terminal:

```
heroku create the-name-i-want

git push heroku master
```

throw error

```
fatal: 'heorku' does not appear to be a git repository
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.
```

or

```
git push heroku the-name-i-want master
```

or

```
git push the-name-i-want master
```

throw error

```
fatal: 'the-name-i-want' does not appear to be a git repository
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.
```

How do you deploy your code to heroku with a custom name, using git?
I use Windows 10.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are conflating two concepts: `heroku` in the examples is the name of the *git remote*, not the application.

Let's walk through that: `git push heroku master` pushes your current branch to the *remote called* `heroku` to branch `master`.

When you `heroku create the-name-i-want` you still get a git remote called `heroku`.

When you want to change the remote's *name*, instead of

```
git remote rename generated-name the-name-i-want
```

use

```
git remote rename heroku the-name-i-want
```

Then you can

```
git push the-name-i-want master
```

That's why you got the error `fatal: 'the-name-i-want' does not appear to be a git repository`

Check your remote names and URLs with `git remote -v`.

Comment: @Viet Pleasure!